# Insertion Sort Data Algorithm explanation?

Tags: python, algorithm

Hello I am trying to understand the insertionSort algorithm.

```
def insertionSort(array):
for i in range(1, len(array)):
    j = i
    while j > 0 and array[j - 1] > array[j]:
        print('array[j-1]', array[j - 1], 'array[j]', array[j])
        swap(j, j - 1, array)
        j -= 1
        print('j', j)
return array

def swap(i, j, array):
    array[i], array[j] = array[j], array[i]
```

I understand we are looping through the array starting from index 1 and setting j to the index i, and while j is greater than 0 and the next array item is greater than the current array item we are going to swap the lesser array item with the greater array item.

The problem I dont understand is, for an example like
when array = [8, 5, 2, 9, 5, 6, 3],

[image]

on the 4th iteration how did j become 3 ?

Comment: Fourth iteration of which loop?

Comment: `j` always starts with the value of `i`. Does that answer your question? You'll getter a better feel of the process when you also log something in the outer loop.

Comment: You're only printing when 1. Something needs to be swapped. 2. After j has been decremented. Nothing happens in the loop where j starts out as being 3. At that point your array looks like this: [2, 5, 8, 9, 5, 6, 3] and the j-index looks at 9 and since 8 is not greater than 9, nothing happens.

Comment: i understand j gets decremented by 1 every time swap happens, so my question is how does it go from 0 to 3 ?

Comment: j does not go from 0 to 3 inside the while loop.  those values of j are from different iterations of the _outer_ loop.

Comment: Like I wrote above, `j` gets its (higher) value from `i`. And as you can see `i` increases.

Comment: I suggest you add `print("outer:", "array =", array, 'j:', j, "array[j] =", array[j])` to just after you set j to i in your outer loop.